# How to return the arguments in constructor as they were entered

Tags: python, constructor

I want to construct this class as a method + arguments, and then have it call the method in the same way.

```
class Event(object):
    def __init__(self, method, *args):
        self.method = method
        if len(args) == 0:
            self.args = None
        else:
            if len(args) == 1:
                if args[0]:
                    self.args = args[0]
                else:
                    self.args = None
            elif len(args) >= 2:
                self.args = list(args)

    def __call__(self, handlers):
        obj = handlers[self.key]
        fn = getattr(obj, self.method)

        if self.args:
            if type(self.args) is list:
                fn(*self.args)
            else:
                fn(self.args)
        else:
            fn()
```

And it works fine in most cases:

```
SystemEvent('add_player', player.name, player.faction)
```

But it fails if one of the arguments is supposed to be a list, like this:

```
class Game:
    def move_agent(self, waypoints):
        #for step in waypoints:

GameEvent('move_agent', [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)])

...
TypeError: move_agent() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Basically, I want to be able to put any format of arguments in the constructor, and have them call the target function the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to convert the `args` received. Why not simply:

```
class Event(object):
    def __init__(self, method_name, *args):
        self.method_name = method_name
        # Store args unconditionally.
        self.args = args

    def __call__(self, obj):
        # Now you can always use *self.args without checking its type.
        getattr(obj, self.method_name)(*self.args)

class A(object):
    def method(self, args):
        print(args)

a = A()
Event('method', [1, 2, 3])(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Argument as

```
GameEvent('move_agent', [((1,1),(2,2),(3,3))])
```

It will take as a single tuple. you dont't need to pass three different tuple as an arguments.